# Roots property of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots

How do I prove the following statement:

> Let $P$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb Q[X]$. If $a$,
>
> $d\in\mathbb Q$, where $\sqrt{d}$ is not
> rational and $P(x_1)=0$, where
>
> $x_1=a+\sqrt{d}$, then $x_2=a-\sqrt{d}$ is also a
>
> solution to the equation $P(x)=0$ ($P(x_2)=0$).

Comment: Hint : use division algorithm f(x)=(x-(a+√d))(x-(a-√d))q(x)+ (Ax+B). Then put x=a+√d and prove that A=0=B

Comment: @Geeky me, what has the reference to vietas relation to do with the proof for the statement above?

Comment: i have removed that comment.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*:

a) Consider the set $\{m+n\sqrt d:m,n\in\Bbb Q\}$. This set is often called $\Bbb Q(\sqrt d)$. Define also $f:\Bbb Q(\sqrt d)\to \Bbb Q(\sqrt d)$ as $f(m+n\sqrt d)=m-n\sqrt d$. Show that $f(\alpha+\beta)=f(\alpha)+f(\beta)$ and that $f(\alpha\beta)=f(\alpha)f(\beta)$ for every $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt d)$.

b) Conclude that $f(P(\alpha))=P(f(\alpha))$ for any $\alpha\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt d)$ and $P\in\Bbb Q[X]$.

c) Apply the previous point assuming that $P(\alpha)=0$.

EDIT: Maybe a word about a) is needed. The function $f$ is well defined because every number in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt d)$ can be written as $m+n\sqrt d$ in only one way (that is, $m+n\sqrt d=m'+n'\sqrt d$ $\implies$ $m=m'$ and $n=n'$). You should prove this, too.

Comment: thanks so much for your help! I found the rest of solvation :D

Answer (score 0):

Split $\,\ P(a +x)\, =:\, f(x)\ =\ \overbrace{g(x^2)+x\, h(x^2)}^{\large\rm\ even\ \,+\,\ odd\ parts},\, $ for $\, g,h\in\Bbb Q[x].$

$\ \ 0 = P(a\!+\!\sqrt d) = f(\sqrt d) = g(d)+\sqrt d\, h(d),\,$ so $\,h(d) = 0\,$ (else $\sqrt d = -g(d)/h(d)\in\Bbb Q).\ $

So $\,\ P(a\!-\!\sqrt d) = f(-\sqrt{d}) = g(d) = 0.$